# Why are there so many different types of 'nuts' in Final Fantasy 7?

Tags: final-fantasy-7

Only a few nuts are required to get the Gold Chocobo..

What good are these nuts? I don't need them for a gold chocobo, so I don't know what they're good for.

Comment: Why do so many chocobo exist in the game if only gold is needed?

Comment: FYI the question wasn't about game design.. I simply don't know what the nuts are for beyond chocobo breeding.. The answer below solves my question.

Comment: I would encourage you to edit your question to focus on that aspect; as it's written, it's rather easy to read this as asking, "Why do these nuts exist?".  Perhaps try, "What good are these nuts?  I don't need them for a gold chocobo, so I don't know what they're good for."

Comment: You might also want to edit the title (same reason as above). Perhaps "what effect do the different nuts have?"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Much like the greens you can feed to chocobos have different effects on their stats, the different nuts have different effects on the newborn chocobo's base stats. I think the reason you see that only a few nuts are needed to get a gold chocobo is because someone figured out the mechanics and devised an optimal path to obtaining a gold chocobo. I've found the following guide to have the most detail about raising and breeding chocobos: http://www.gamefaqs.com/ps/197341-final-fantasy-vii/faqs/58077

Hope this helps.